# installed libopencv results in blackscreen after login

Tags: nvidia, ati, opencv

I am new to Ubuntu and set it up a few days ago. Now I wanted to install OpenCV since I need this for university matters.

After turning off my pc I was able to log in but afterwards just a black screen appeared. The mouse is able to move and also the terminal can be called with Ctrl+alt+t.

I read in some forums that the `libopencv` may crashs with my AMD graphic card. But I do not not know how I solve this problem. I removed the nvidia-319 driver but it says there is nothing installed.

So i don´t know what the problem is. I hope someone could help me.

Comment: Could you add to your question how did you intall opencv (repo or from source) and a link to such forum thread please?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have this exact bug:

[Installing libopencv-dev breaks OpenGl for Intel based gpu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/opencv/+bug/1245260)

You just have to remove **ALL** the nvidia packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

And install the following new dependencies to get support for OpenCL:

```
sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-libopencl1
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: And sorry for this question, but how do I know which version I installed? nvidia-*

Comment: nvidia-* will not only remove nvidia-319 but also nvidia-settings, nvidia-common all nvidia related packages. You really don't need them since you have an AMD card

Comment: Did the above commands solve your problem?